# check whether a table has header or not in R

Tags: r, file, input, header

I'm reading a file which contains a tabular data. I want to check if the first row of the data is a header or not. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: wouldn't head(data) be sufficient ? Then you can specify if the first row is a header with header=T of F in your read.table call.

Comment: couple of ways of doing this. 
are you calling read.table with header = T? you could compare `read.table(file, header = T, nrow = 2)` with `read.table(file, header = F, nrow = 2)`

Comment: @Chargaff Could you please explain more? I use head() to get the first n lines. how do I know if the first line is a header or not?

Comment: What command did you use to read your data ?

Comment: If you're trying to do it programmatically without manually checking, then if you're certain the data components are going to be numeric only you could use that fact to read in the file and see if the first line has characters and either ignore them or use them as the column names. Apart from that, you'll need to spot-check it.

Comment: @infominer I'm not getting it. what's this comparison going to show?I want to know if the file has a header or not

Comment: @Elahehkamaliha, try the code and see if the output looks different, specifically if you see different values in row 1 then you have no header and otherwise

Comment: You could try `fread` in the `data.table` package: It can be hit or miss, but often it will automatically detect whether the data has a header or not.