# determining type of data in the input file

Tags: r, file, types, data.table

I am reading a file with the first two lines like this(the cols are space seperated) :

c1 c2 c3 c4 c5

1   2  3  4  5

I want to read the first two line and determine if the first line is a character vector or numeric vector? (in the example above, it is character, but it can be numeric in other files).

How can I do that? I tried using read.table, data.table and fread, but none of them works properly. read.table converts every element into integer. Can you help me with an easy way to do this?

Comment: Is the point here that some files have headers and some don't?

Comment: @jlhoward, yes, I want to detect if the file has header or not

Comment: @Elahehkamaliha, then how does this question differ from your previous: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22413199/check-whether-a-table-has-header-or-not-in-r

Comment: @Henrik I tried to make it more general. Here, I'm asking only how I can get the type of each cell in the file (char, numeric, ...)

Comment: @Elahehkamaliha, several ways were suggested in the comments to your previous question. Sharing your attempts helps everyone. Please show us the code you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, and it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something along the lines of

```
twoLines <- readLines("myFile", nrow=2)
firstLineFields <- strsplit(twoLines, " ")[[1]]
allNumeric <- !any(is.na(as.numeric(firstLineFields)))
allChar <- all(is.na(as.numeric(firstLineFields)))
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you.

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(5),ncol=5))
write.table(df, "hdr.txt", sep=" ")
write.table(df, "nohdr.txt", sep=" ",col.names=F)

input <- read.table("hdr.txt",colClasses="character",nrows=1) # grab first line
hdr   <- any(is.na(as.numeric(input)))                   # hdr=T if any character
hdr
# [1] TRUE

input <- read.table("nohdr.txt",colClasses="character",nrows=1) # grab first line
hdr   <- any(is.na(as.numeric(input)))                   # hdr=F if all numeric
hdr
# [1] FALSE
data  <- read.table(header=hdr,...)
```

So read the first line, coercing everything to character. Applying the `as.numeric(...)` function to that will return `NA` for any elements that cannot be coerced to numeric. If that happens, you've got a header.

Comment: not working, I think read.table returns all the element as integer by default. my file has a header but hdr is false when I use your solution

Comment: Sorry, should have been `as.numeric(...)`, not `is.numeric(...)`. That's what I get for not testing it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you just looking for the `str` function?

```
df <- data.frame(number_column = c(1, 2, 3),
                 factor_Column = c('a', 'b', 'c'),
                 date_column = as.Date(c('2014-01-01', '2014-01-01', '2014-01-01'),
                                      format = '%Y-%m-%d'))       
str(df)

'data.frame':   3 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ number_column: num  1 2 3
 $ factor_Column: Factor w/ 3 levels "a","b","c": 1 2 3
 $ date_column  : Date, format: "2014-01-01" "2014-01-01" ...
```